# Check if environmental variable is set in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following  code in `MAKEFILE` , using this , I want to print info in accordance with whether a flag is set or not

```
ifeq ($(SET_FLAG),)
$(info ********not set************)
else
$(info *******set *********)
endif
```

However this gives me output as

```
********not set************
```

when on the terminal I do `setenv SET_FLAG`

and this

```
*******set *********
```

when I do `setenv SET_FLAG 1`

However I want to test only if `SET_FLAG` is set or not , no matter value being provided or not.
Is there any way so that it gives output of above as

```
*******set *********
```

even when i do `setenv SET_FLAG`

Comment: This is a good example of a question made difficult to read by lack of correct punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make, you can use a workaround like

```
ifeq ($(origin SET_FLAG),undefined)
    $(info not set)
else
    $(info set)
endif
```

More or less cribbed from http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html

As an aside, `setenv` suggests that you are using `t?csh`.  Using a standard, Bourne-compatible shell (if only in the context of your question) would probably help you get timely and correct answers.